How to listen to call status in android?
I'm trying my best to track the listener's call status but having some problems when stopping the app, the app fails to track when a call comes in.
Manifest
permission
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />


register broadcast receiver
<receiver
            android:name=".service.CallBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

handle when call state change
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        try {
            if (intent.action == TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) {
                val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

                when (state) {

                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
                        handleInComingCall(context)
                    }

                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                        handleOutgoingCall(context)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.message
        }

    }

thanks for any solution that help me!^^

What do you mean by "stopping the app"? Explain how you "stop the app"?
